Schreier's theorem for non-abelian cohomology
$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$Let $A$ by $G$ be two non-abelian group. A factor pair of $G$ with coefficients in $A$ is a pair $(\alpha,\varepsilon)$, where $\alpha:G\rightarrow\Aut(A)$ and $\varepsilon:G\times G\rightarrow A$ are maps satisfying the following properties:
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha(1)&=&\mathrm{id}_{A},\\
\label{normlized}
\varepsilon(h,1)&=&\varepsilon(1,h)=1, \\
\label{map}
\alpha(h)\circ\alpha(g)&=&\varepsilon(h,g)\alpha(hg)\varepsilon(h,g)^{-1},\\
\label{Cocycle}
\varepsilon(h,g)\varepsilon (hg,k)&=&\alpha (h)(\varepsilon
(g,k))\varepsilon (h,gk)
\end{eqnarray}
for all $g, h, k\in G$. The set of factor pairs of $G$ with coefficients in $A$ is denoted by $\mathcal{Z}^{2}(G,A)$.  Let $(\alpha,\varepsilon)$, $(\beta,\varepsilon')\in \mathcal{Z}^{2}(G,A)$, we write $(\alpha,\varepsilon)\sim(\beta,\varepsilon')$ and say that $(\alpha,\varepsilon)$ and $(\beta,\varepsilon')$ are cohomologous if there is a map $t:G\to A$ such that
$$\beta(g)=t(g)\alpha(g)t(g)^{-1} \text{ and }
 \varepsilon'(g,h)=t(g)\alpha(g)(t(h))\varepsilon(g,h)t(gh)^{-1}$$
for all $g$, $h\in G$. The set of cohomology classes of factor pairs of $G$ with coefficients in $A$ is denoted by $\mathcal{H}^{2}(G,A)$.
Now, two extensions $E$ and $E'$ of $A$ by $G$ are said to be equivalent if and only there is a homomorphism  $\varphi:E\rightarrow E'$ such that the
following diagram commutes
\begin{equation*}\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>>> A @>>> E @>>>G @>>> 1 \\
@. @| @VV\varphi V @| \\
1 @>>> A @>>> E' @>>> G @>>> 1.
\end{CD}
\end{equation*} The set of equivalence classes of group extensions is denoted by $\Ext(G,A)$.
Schreier's Theorem gives us a one-to-one correspondence between $\Ext(G,A)$ and $H^{2}(G,Z(A))$. But I can't find a direct proof for this theorem. In other word, I want to understand how a given extension induces a factor pair $(\alpha,\varepsilon)$ where the $2$-cocycle
$\varepsilon$ takes values in the center $Z(A)$ of $A$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Don't you want $H^3(G,Z(A))$

Not exactly. In fact, there is a proof using the free and the transitive action of $H^{2}(G,Z(A))$ on $Ext(G,A)$. Here, I'm looking for a direct proof. More precisely, I want to understand how a given extension induces a factor pair $(\alpha,\varepsilon)$ where the cocycle
$\varepsilon$ takes values in the center $Z(A)$ of $A$.

What if Z(A)=1?

@Richard Lyons In this case, I think every extension of A by G splits.

@N. SNANOU: It is not true that every extension of $A$ by $G$ splits if $Z(A)=1$. For example, let $H$ be the (split) extension of the additive group $N=F_5^+$ by the multiplicative group $C=F_5^\times$ acting naturally (where $F_5$ is the field of $5$ elements). Then $H$ has a subgroup $A$ of index $2$ isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $10$, and $G=H/A\cong Z_2$. Here $Z(A)=1$ but $H$ is not a split extension of $A$ by $G$. You may object that $G$ is abelian, but you can take any nonabelian group $K$ and form $H\times K$, a nonsplit extension of the same $A$ by $Z_2\times K$.

@Richard Lyons Thank you for the example. Suppose $Z(A)=1$ and let  $f:G\rightarrow Out(A)$ be a group homomorphism, is it true that there exists an extension of A by G inducing  $f$. Further, How your assymption help us to answer the question.

@N. SNANOU Yes, if $Z(A)=1$ then there is an extension inducing $f$. You can start building it by taking the pullback of $f$ and the canonical homomorphism from $Aut(A)$ to $Out(A)$. Chasing diagrams will show that you have an extension of $Inn(A)\cong A$ by $G$. As for your question, given $f$, there is a way to construct a $3$-cocycle on $G$ with values in $Z(A)$, and such that an extension of $A$ by $G$ exists affording $f$ if and only if the $3$-cocycle is a coboundary. This may give a hint for your desired elementary proof. It is discussed for example in Mac Lane's old text "Homology."

I think your question is discussed explicitly in a bachelor thesis from 2017: "Classifying group extensions with not necessarily abelian kernel" by Chen Zhang.
